# If $k<n$ then $S_{k+1}^{n+1}=S_{k}^{n}+S_{k+1}^{n}$ ($S_{k}^{n}$= n choose k)

Tags: combinatorics, solution-verification

Prove the following theorem:

Theorem: if $k<n$ then $S_{k+1}^{n+1}=S_{k}^{n}+S_{k+1}^{n}$ ($S_{k}^{n}$= n choose k)

Proof

$Left=S_{k+1}^{n+1}$

what left does is to count all possible subsets of k+1 elements out n+1.

$Right=S_{k}^{n}+S_{k+1}^{n}$

Let's consider the sets which contain  the n+1 element  $$S=\{ ..............,n+1\}$$

To fill up the remaining k spots, we choose k out of n elements, so the number of subsets which contain the n+1 element is $S_{k}^{n}$

Now if we consider the sets which don't contain the n+1 element, we simply discard the n+1 element and fill up the k+1 spots with the remaining n elements. Therefore, the number of subsets which don't contain the n+1 element is $S_{k+1}^{n}$.

Hence every set either contains or doesnt contain the n+1 element, we conclude that counting  these sets is equivalent to counting all possible subsets of k+1 elements out of n+1 elements , so $left=right$.

This is mostly a writing class, so I would be glad if I get help with my writing and of course the logic of the math.

Comment: I am unfamiliar with the notation $S_k^n$. What does it mean? The number of size $k$ subsets of a set with $n$ elements?

Comment: it's equivalent to n choose k

Comment: Stirling numbers of the second kind are definitely not equivalent to n choose k, otherwise why would we call them Stirling numbers of the second kind? You basically said this in your other post and it was wrong then. If you want to prove things about n choose k, we can do that instead.

Comment: yes that's how the professor defines it. Don't get confused about stirling numbers. I already specified above that it is n choose k

Comment: I think you will get a better response if you use standard notation. The number of $k$-element subsets of an $n$-element set is $\binom{n}{k}$ or $C(n,k)$ or $_{n}C_{k}$.

Answer (score 0):

So you would like to prove that $\binom{n+1}{k+1} = \binom{n}{k} + \binom{n}{k+1} .$ There so many ways for proving this identity. One method is the following:

Let's count the number of ways to choose $k+1$ elements from an $n+1$ set. By definition, the left hand side of the equation is the number of ways to choose $k+1$ from $n+1$. Since $1 ≤ k+1 ≤ n $, we can pick a fixed element $\alpha$ from the $n+1$ set so that the remaining subset is not empty. For each $k+1$ set, if $\alpha$ is chosen, there are ${n \choose k}$
ways to choose the remaining $k $ elements among the remaining $n$ choices; otherwise, there are ${n \choose k+1}$ ways to choose the remaining $k+1$ elements among the remaining $n$ choices. Thus, there are
${n \choose k} + {n \choose k+1}$
ways to choose k elements depending on whether $\alpha$ is included in each selection, as in the right hand side expression. $\blacksquare$